# Numerical Reasoning - Percentage decrease\increase in revenue

Tags: numerical-methods, percentages

This is a fairly simple question I believe, but I'm not able to come to a solution

In 2015, the percentage of revenue from IT division of my company was 30%

In 2016,  the percentage of revenue from IT division of my company was 25%

If the total revenue increased by 20%, by how much did the contribution from IT division increase\decrease?

Any suggestions on how to go about it?

Comment: Just write everything out.  $IT_{2015}=.3\times T_{2015},IT_{2016}=.25\times T_{2016},T_{2016}=1.2\times T_{2015}$.  You want to compute the ratio $IT_{2016}/IT_{2015}$.

Comment: @lulu Thanks. I think it gives me 0%, is that right?

Comment: Let's see:  I get $IT_{2016}=.25\times 1.2\times T_{2015}\implies \frac {IT_{2016}}{IT_{2015}}=\frac {.25\times 1.2}{.3}=1$  So, I agree.  $IT_{2016}=IT_{2015}$.